# Unwrapping of a ref variable declared in a class - vue3

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

In Vue3 I've created several Classes with ref and computed values inside, for example:

```vue3
class BaseBlock {
  id = "XXXXX"

  run = ref(false)
  disabled = ref(false)
  alarm = ref(false)
  ready = ref(false)
  energySaving = ref(false)
  resetNeed = ref(false)
  activeCycle = ref(false)

  n0 = {
    status: ref(false),
    sigla: "XXX",
    title: "Alarm 0",
    description: "Alarm 0 is active",
    action: "Contact Saiet Engineering Customer Care",
    color: COLORS.red,
  }
  n1 = {
    status: ref(false),
    sigla: "XXX",
    title: "Alarm 1",
    description: "Alarm 1 is active",
    action: "Contact Saiet Engineering Customer Care",
    color: COLORS.red,
  }
  constructor(id) {
    this.id = id
    this.runText = `The element ${id} is running as expected`
    this.disabledText = `The element ${id} is currently DISABLED`

    // activeAlarms is a computed array that keeps all currently active alarms in priority order
    this.activeAlarms = computed(() => {
      let activeArray = [];
      for (let alarmId of this.alarmPriority) {
        if (this[alarmId].status.value) activeArray.push(alarmId)
      }
      return activeArray
    })
    // if there are active alarms, color will return the highest priority alarm color
    this.color = computed(() => {
      // disabled
      if (this.disabled.value) return COLORS.blue
      // running
      if (this.activeAlarms.value[0] == null) {
        if (this.run.value) return COLORS.green
        return 'white'
      }
      // alarms
      return this[this.activeAlarms.value[0]].color
    })
  }
}
```

Notice how in my **computed** properties I call the `.value` of the variable I want to check if it's a ref/computed.

I don't think it matters, but it's worth noting that this class is extended by other classes, without additional computation aside for assigning special values, for example:

```vue3
class Emergency extends BaseBlock {
  alarmPriority = ['n12', 'n13']
  alarms = ['n12', 'n13']

  constructor(id) {
    super(id)   
    Object.assign(
      this.n12, 
      {
        sigla: "SEM1",
        title: "Emergency Memory",
        description: "-",
        action: "-",
      }
    )
    Object.assign(
      this.n13, 
      {
        sigla: "SE1",
        title: "Emercency pushbutton",
        description: "Emergency pushbutton pressed",
        action: "Pull Emergency pushbutton",
      }
    )
  }
}
```

My instances are then created inside a ref:

```vue3
let blocks = ref({
  'MCP01': new MainCabinet('MCP01'),
  'CSW1': new LocalCabinet('CSW1'),
  'CSW2': new LocalCabinet('CSW2'),
  'CSW3': new LocalCabinet('CSW3'),
})
```

Now, let's say I want to change `blocks.value['MCP01'].run` to `true` **somewhere else in my code**, what I'm expecting to do is

```vue3
blocks.value['MCP01'].run.value = true
```

However this **does not work**, I need to do instead:

```vue3
blocks.value['MCP01'].run = true
```

Since I'm not changing `.value` from the the ref, I would expect I'm actually replacing the variable altogether, hence losing reactivity.
**This is not the case**: my class remains (apparently?) reactive everywhere in the code, even my **computed** properties.

My question is: **what's going on? Why my ref are automatically unwrapped like if I was inside the template? Why doesn't reactivity break (or maybe it does, but I haven't realised it yet?)?**

P.S. By searching for similar issues I've realised that the best practice in vue is to avoid altogether classes and use composables instead (e.g. `useBaseBlock` in my example), but it's a bit too late for that in this project, plus I really would like to understand what's going on.

Comment: A ref unwraps all refs inside it. So `let blocks = ref({ /* ... */ })` creates a ref of the object, and unwraps all refs inside it.

Comment: You can see this in the return type: `Ref<UnwrapRef<T>>`

Comment: Relevant docs: If an object is assigned as a ref's value, the object is made deeply reactive with `reactive()`. This also means if the object contains nested refs, they will be deeply unwrapped. To avoid the deep conversion, use `shallowRef()` instead. https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-core.html#ref

Comment: I feel very stupid now... I swear I've tried so hard to look in the doc for an answer, but I just missed this! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If given an object, a ref unwraps all refs inside it.

From [the docs](https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-core.html#ref):

> If an object is assigned as a ref's value, the object is made deeply reactive with `reactive()`. This also means if the object contains nested refs, they will be deeply unwrapped.
>
> To avoid the deep conversion, use `shallowRef()` instead.

You can actually see this in the return type: `Ref<UnwrapRef<T>>`.

So `let blocks = ref({ /* ... */ })` creates a ref of the object, and unwraps all refs inside it.
Hence, the properties that were refs are now exposed as simple values inside the parent ref, and so must be used directly instead of via `.value`.

Comment: Thank you so much, this perfectly answer my question.